# Debug in ES6 short-hand notation - filter, map, reject or reduce

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

How can I place `console.log` in filter, map, reduce or reject using ES6 short-hand?

> ```
> words.filter(word => word.length > 6);
> ```

**ES6 Version**

```js
const words = ["spray", "limit", "elite", "exuberant", "destruction", "present", "happy"];

let longWords = words.filter(word => word.length > 6); //NEED AN EXAMPLE FOR HERE

// Filtered array longWords is ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]

console.log(longWords);
```

**Possible here**

```js
const words = ["spray", "limit", "elite", "exuberant", "destruction", "present", "happy"];

let longWords = words.filter(function(word) {
  console.log(word);
  return word.length > 6;
});
```

Comment: use {} and return....`(word => { console.log(word); return word.length > 6 }`

Comment: no other way to do it without return?

Comment: The comma operator may help: `word => (console.log(word), word.length)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use or since console does not return anything

```
word => console.log(word) || word.length > 6
```

personally I just use brackets and a return if I need to debug

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a reusable snippet that doesn't obscure your key action, you could define a helper first:

```
const firstDo = f => g => (...args) => (f(...args), g(...args));
```

This takes two functions and returns a new one. The new function calls both `f` and `g` with the same arguments, but *returns* the result of `g(...args)`.

This allows you to tap in to `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, `every` etc. and easily remove the logging when debugging is done.

For your `filter` example, a debug logger could be:

```
const logLength = str => console.log(`Length of "${str}": ${str.length}`);
```

Now, you can wrap your predicate in:

```
const tapLog = firstDo(logLength);

const longWords = words.filter(tapLog(x => x > 6));
```

In a working example, with a `reduce` example included:

```js
const words = ["spray", "limit", "elite", "exuberant", "destruction", "present", "happy"];

const firstDo = f => g => (...args) => (f(...args), g(...args));

const logLength = str => console.log(`Length of "${str}": ${str.length}`);



const firstLogLength = firstDo(logLength);

const pred = x => x.length > 6;

// in a filter
console.log(
  words.filter(firstLogLength(pred))
);

// In a reduce
const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
const logSumProg = firstDo((a, b) => console.log(`${a} + ${b}`));

console.log(
  [1,2,3,4,5].reduce(logSumProg(sum))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you want to debug, it is easier to set a conditional breakpoint.

```
let longWords = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);
```

In Firefox debugger you can right click on the line of the code you want to debug. Then choose "Add Conditional Breakpoint", add `typeof word !== 'undefined' && word == 'some word'` for example. Now when you run the code, the execution of the code will be paused when these conditions are met and you can use the usual debugger functions.

You should avoid changing your code just for debugging whenever possible.