# Why is this filter function not working as expected?

Tags: javascript

This code:

```
let rId = requested.map((r) => r._id.toString());
console.log(rId);

let cId = confirmed.map((c) => c._id.toString());
console.log(cId);

rId.filter((r) => !cId.includes(r));
console.log(rId);
```

Prints this:

```
[
  '63bcc18d083dd2c66679e160',
  '63bcc331083dd2c66679e278',
  '63bdaef8f115ae565ac564c5'
]

[ '63bdaef8f115ae565ac564c5' ]

[
  '63bcc18d083dd2c66679e160',
  '63bcc331083dd2c66679e278',
  '63bdaef8f115ae565ac564c5'
]
```

Why is the last item in the array not filtered when the function returns a false statement?

What I'm expecting to be printed is this:

```
[
  '63bcc18d083dd2c66679e160',
  '63bcc331083dd2c66679e278',
  '63bdaef8f115ae565ac564c5'
]

[ '63bdaef8f115ae565ac564c5' ]

[
  '63bcc18d083dd2c66679e160',
  '63bcc331083dd2c66679e278', // <-- item removed
]
```

Comment: `console.log`  returns `undefined`

Comment: Ok, even so, that is run at the end here

Comment: See [How can I place console.log in filter, map, reduce or reject using ES6 short-hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426341/debug-in-es6-short-hand-notation-filter-map-reject-or-reduce)

Comment: I suspect the example is distracting from what you're trying to ask.  Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] and indicate specifically what output is unexpected?  Remove output that isn't relevant to the specific problem.

Comment: `array#filter` returns an array with elements matching the function callback. `array#filter` doesn't modify the existing array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter does not mutate the array it is called on.

You need to set the result of the filter to a value;

```js
rId = rId.filter((r) => !cId.includes(r));
```

Answer (score 3):

`filter` does not change the original array. You should assign the result to a variable.

```js
rId = rId.filter((r) => !cId.includes(r));
console.log(rId);
```

Comment: Ignoring the final function, the filter on line 5 is not working as expected